# Getting all the threads waiting for an object before calling notifyAll

Tags: java, multithreading

I have bunch of code & the processor is small,
when calling `notifyAll`, sometimes creating performance issue (100ms) so I want to know what are the threads currently waiting for the object to get released.

```
synchronized (obj){
//do some stuff..
obj.notifyall();
}
```

I want to print all the threads waiting for the object to get released before calling `obj.notifyAll()`

Comment: If you want all the threads to stop waiting before notifying, what would be the point with calling notifyAll()? Anyway, I don't think it is doable using the java synchronization, you might have to invent some locking yourself using the locks available (and some barrier or something to keep track of them).

Comment: thanks.. accepted my previous questions.. answer.. , i was not aware of that..   , i will take care now onwards.. , 
& i don't want previous thread to stop waiting , i may debug those thread.. & check if the particular thread was necessary or not...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are all the threads waiting on the resource for the same condition? If yes, then you can try replacing `obj.notify()` instead of `obj.notifyAll` though it really isn't recommended. AFAIK, there is no way of "retrieving" a list of all the threads waiting on a given object (though you can  programatically get a thread-dump of the process and view the threads, but I'm sure that's not what you had in mind). Even if there was, listing threads and then doing "something" with them would surely take more than the time taken to `notifyAll`.

Also, if the "processor is small", try limiting the number of threads spawned since without a fair amount of "real" threads, creating too many threads is typically an overhead. That way, `notifyAll` wouldn't wake up a bunch of threads.

Here is a small program which demonstrates dumping of thread state information with comments inlined:

```
package net.sanjayts.test;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadInfo;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadDumpTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Object lock = new Object();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            final int cnt = i;
            new DaemonThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // If counter is even, try to acquire common lock and then
                        // sleep. If odd, sleep without trying to acquire the lock.
                        // This way, if we do a thread dump, we'll see threads in
                        // different states (TIMED_WAIT for those sleeping threads
                        // and BLOCKED for those waiting for the common "lock".
                        if (cnt % 2 == 0) {
                            synchronized (lock) {
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1); // sleep 1 min
                            }
                        } else {
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1); // sleep 1 min
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, "mythread-" + cnt).start();
        }
        ThreadInfo[] infos = ManagementFactory.
                getThreadMXBean().dumpAllThreads(true, true);
        for (ThreadInfo info : infos) {
            System.out.println(info);
            System.out.println("===========================");
        }
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
    }

}

class DaemonThread extends Thread {
    public DaemonThread(Runnable r, String name) {
        super(r, name);
        setDaemon(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh , i want to list them just for debugging purpose...  , thanks for the answer, i will try printing all the thread dumps. that can give me idea, 
since i have two project one is changed version of that, & & i am comparing them , i expect notifyall should take same amount of time in both the places ,
i think thread dump will solve the problem... will try it...

Comment: I have edited the post with a sample snippet which will dump the thread information which includes the state of the thread along with the "lock" information, if any. Good luck.

Comment: @KalpeshSoni: Yes though you are better off using the "management console" offered by the JEE containers for these sort of things or VisualVM. Maybe something like [this for JBoss](http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/knowing-jboss-as-memory-and-thread-info-using-jmx-console/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Thread.getAllStackTraces() and print out all the threads which are waiting.