# get lock object thread is waiting on

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

How could I get lock object [Thread](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/lang/Thread.html) is waiting on?

I have thread dump and I can see one SwingWorker started a confirmation dialog using invokeAndWait() awaiting user interaction.
How could I detect this scenario programmatically?

```
    "Some swing worker -1-thread-8", WAITING, prio=5, tid=128
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1038)
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1326)
        at ...
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I posted a similar answer a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652566/getting-all-the-threads-waiting-for-an-object-before-calling-notifyall/8652637#8652637). The trick is to use Management extensions provided by the JDK in case you are interested in the status of all the running threads.

Answer (score 1):

See the [`Thread.holdsLock(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#holdsLock%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

AFAICT this is the only way to determine if a thread holds a lock on a particular object; I don't think there is a way to programmatically access the object on which a thread is waiting without knowing which one(s) it might be ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Basiclly a lock has a list of the threads waiting on him,
the lock here is an object's lock, therefore it's a Monitor object.

even if you do get access to the list (which is unlikly,due to concurrency and security reasons) it would be almost impossible to guarantee you'll get the correct list at a specific time every time.

*you may find the following printouts usefull,try getting the monitor's list by the thread using it and printing before releasing the lock(for example monitor's method -> See the [`getObservedObjects()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/monitor/Monitor.html#getObservedObjects%28%29) method. ),and also make sure every thread writes his id before acquiring,both may result in an incorrect temporary values,but combined it would give you an indication to your needs.*

Comment: I'm trying to find lock in case when I have a (reference to) Thread, but not the versa. Welcome on board ;)

Comment: tnx, the Object has a private field called _lock,you may not access and manipulate it explicitly from high level(it may be possible from jvm language) and it is accessed implicity with the keyword synchronized and other methods as you already know,if you were allowed-> deadlock\livelock and more would be much more common and hard to trace